# Signing Application-Data-Sheet (ADS) Using EFS-Web

Tags: filing

This is the first time to file my application using USPTO's EFS-Web service. When I used the regular mail, the ADS document is always signed by hand, while here with EFS-Web I'm facing the following contradiction:

If I sign on it by hand (i.e., handwritten signature), then I have to scan it before uploading it. If I try to upload that scanned PDF document using EFS-Web, I received a warning message said: the file template is not compatible with ADS template!

Should I ignore that warning and go forward with the scanned ADS or should I stick with the original readable ADS and use S-Signature?

I'm thinking to sign on that readable PDF file using S-Signature, but I'm afraid that USPTO may contact me later and asking me for a one missing part >> which is about: "The ADS received on xxxxxx was not properly signed"

What are your experiences with this problem? Do you use handwritten or S-Signature when you use EFS-Web?

Answer (score 1):

After few searches, I found the answer in the following example given by USPTO:
https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/aia_implementation/oath_declaration_examples.pdf

I put it just in case someone faces the same problem

Comment: If you expand this, it could be reposted as an answer. We are allowed to answer our own questions.